# uninstalled deb file shows up on menu

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, uninstall, skype, cinnamon

running ubuntu cinnamon 64-bit 13.04 and having an issue I haven't faced before.

I recently installed and uninstalled skype using their deb package, but the .deb file keeps popping up on my menu screen when I type in skype.  I've uninstalled it, ran synaptic to remove all packages related to skype, and searched my file system and my home folders to see if the deb file was still lurking about somewhere - nothing.

here's what keeps popping up:
[http://imgur.com/KBDK05H](https://imgur.com/KBDK05H)

it's a small issue but incredibly annoying.  TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
```

If you find it in any of these places delete it.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply!  

I went to the file, and it only had one file 'mimeapps.list.'  When I opened it, it had a small list of default applications, but none of them mentioned skype.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please see if you cand find skype in any of these locations.

Comment: Thanks again - I'm still not seeing it.  I've checked all those places and also ran 

     find / -name 'skype*'  

there were three files, but they were image files (png) and no .deb files turned up.